# Can I say "class notes" instead of "lecture notes"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Can I say ***class notes*** instead of ***lecture notes***? Do these phrases have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "class notes" can be used. It has a somewhat wider meaning. "Lecture notes" are specifically notes taken during a lecture. "Class notes" could refer to notes during a lab class, or a discussion seminar. It could also refer to pre-published notes such as those sold as notes on certian literary works, particularly by "Cliff notes".